# Restarting Akka Actor and Reactive Streams Integration

Tags: akka

I have a scenario where I have to restart a child Actor from within a parent actor. The restart should happen with the following rules:

1. The start should happen only after stop has been completed
2. Both the stop and start should happen asynchronously

I now have the following scenario:

In my parent Actor, I have a Monix Observable which is pushing events as below:

```
class ParentActor extends Actor {
  ...

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()

    // Observable to stream events regarding PowerPlant's
    val powerPlantEventObservable =
    // For every config.database.refreshInterval in seconds
      Observable.interval(config.database.refreshInterval)
        // We ask the actor for the latest messages
        .map(_ => (dbServiceActor ? DBServiceActor.PowerPlantEvents).mapTo[PowerPlantEventsSeq])
        .concatMap(Observable.fromFuture(_))
        .concatMap(Observable.fromIterable(_))

    // Subscriber that pipes the messages to this Actor
    cancelable := powerPlantEventObservable.subscribe { update =>
      (self ? update).map(_ => Continue)
    }
  }
}
```

So what happens above is that, I'm asking another Actor called DBServiceActor for a List of events and when these events are available, I'm piping it to the ParentActor (self ? update). The receive method of the ParentActor looks like this and this is where I want to restart my child actor . asynchronously:

```
    override def receive: Receive = {

        case PowerPlantUpdateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg) =>
          log.info(s"Re-starting PowerPlant actor with id = $id and type ${powerPlantCfg.powerPlantType}")

          // I want to stop the actor first by finding it from the actor system
          // If it exists, do a context.stop on the Actor instance
          // Once it is stopped, I want to start it again by creating a new instance of this Actor
          // Once this new Actor instance is created, I want to signal my Monix Observer to send me the next event
      }
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: So here is the new receive method as per suggestions from the post below:

```
def receive: Receive = {

    // TODO: When I restart, I need the powerPlantCfg!!! How to get it?
    case Terminated(actorRef) =>
      context.unwatch(actorRef)

    case PowerPlantCreateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg) =>
      log.info(s"Starting PowerPlant actor with id = $id and type ${powerPlantCfg.powerPlantType}")

      // Start the PowerPlant, and pipe the message to self
      startPowerPlant(id, powerPlantCfg).pipeTo(self)

    case PowerPlantUpdateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg) =>
      log.info(s"Re-starting PowerPlant actor with id = $id and type ${powerPlantCfg.powerPlantType}")

      context.child(s"$simulatorActorNamePrefix$id") match {
        case Some(actorRef) =>
          context.watch(actorRef)
          actorRef ! PoisonPill


        case None =>
          log.warning(s"No running actor instance found for id $id :: Creating a new instance")
          self ! PowerPlantCreateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg)
      }

    case PowerPlantDeleteEvent(id, powerPlantCfg) => // TODO
      log.info(s"Stopping PowerPlant actor with id = $id and type ${powerPlantCfg.powerPlantType}")

      context.child(s"$simulatorActorNamePrefix$id") match {
        case Some(actorRef) =>
          context.watch(actorRef)
          actorRef ! PoisonPill

        case None =>
          log.warning(s"No running actor instance found for id $id")
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
// I want to stop the actor first by finding it from the actor system
```

To find a child, use `val child = context.child(name)` or browse through `context.children`

```
// If it exists, do a context.stop on the Actor instance
```

With the child found above, you have to setup death-watch (useful for the next step) and kill it:

```
context.watch(child) // you could also consider using context.watchWith()
child ! PoisonPill
```

.

```
// Once it is stopped, I want to start it again by creating a new instance of this Actor
```

Your `ParentActor` will be notified that the child stopped thanks to the deatch-watch setup above, just add a message handler:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case Terminated(child) => // you might want to check which specific child was terminated if you care
    context.unwatch(child)
    context.actorOf(...) // recreate the child actor
```

.

```
// Once this new Actor instance is created, I want to signal my Monix Observer to send me the next event
```

You can signal the creation right after calling `context.actorOf`, if you want to be sure the child actor managed to start (i.e., because something is likely to fail during its initialization/start), you should have your `ParentActor` expect a signal from the newly created child. You can send that signal from child to parent in `preStart()`, or in one of its message handler if the startup is more complex.

Comment: Where do I unwatch again?

Comment: The problem I see is that the current message is done immediately after sending a PoisonPill and right over there the signal to the Monix observer is done which means that the Observer is going to push the next message into my Receive. But I would like to avoid that and have the Monix observer push the next message only after I have re-started this new instance like in the Terminated(child) block as above.

Comment: I have added the block in my original post that shows how I'm piping messages from my Monix observer into this Actor

Comment: for your first comment, I edited my answer. For the rest, I would suggest you stash the messages until the child is restarted. See akka's doc for stashing messages.

Comment: Stashing might work! Thanks for the suggestions! You helped me!

Comment: I edited my post with your suggestions! I'm sort of stuck right now as you can see that in the Terminated(actorRef), I just cannot restart the child because that child needs the new configuration object which I get from the Monix Observable!

Comment: Re-starting the actor in the Terminated(actorRef) might not work as I should also completely stop some actors!

Comment: Keep that configuration object in the actor state, when you start the new child, pass the configuration as a constructor parameter.

Comment: By Actor state you mean a var? I would avoid doing that! I could of-course do the context.become and pass the state around, but I can't see how that might work! My receive method works by getting messages from a Stream and by doing context become I cannot see how I could keep the states between subsequent messages

Comment: I somehow managed to formulate this. Can you take a look at my solution below and validate if this is Okay?

Answer (score 0):

So based on the answer from Frederic A, I'm posting my solution here that shows how to handle re-starts of an Actor:

```
def waitForRestart(source: ActorRef, newMessage: Option[PowerPlantCreateEvent[PowerPlantConfig]]): Receive = {
    case Terminated(actor) =>
      context.unwatch(actor)

      newMessage match {
        case Some(powerPlantCreateEvent) =>
          self ! powerPlantCreateEvent
        case _ =>
          // just ignore
      }
      // Now unstash all of the messages
      unstashAll()

    case someDamnThing =>
      log.error(s"Unexpected message $someDamnThing :: " +
        s"received while waiting for an actor to be stopped")
      stash()
  }
```

Here is the receive method:

```
def receive: Receive = {

        case Terminated(actorRef) =>
          context.unwatch(actorRef)

        case PowerPlantCreateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg) =>
          log.info(s"Starting PowerPlant actor with id = $id and type ${powerPlantCfg.powerPlantType}")

          // Start the PowerPlant, and pipe the message to self
          startPowerPlant(id, powerPlantCfg).pipeTo(self)

        case PowerPlantUpdateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg) =>
          log.info(s"Re-starting PowerPlant actor with id = $id and type ${powerPlantCfg.powerPlantType}")

          context.child(s"$simulatorActorNamePrefix$id") match {
            case Some(actorRef) =>
              context.watch(actorRef)
              // We first kill
              actorRef ! PoisonPill

              // We wait asynchronously until this Actor is re-started
              context.become(
                waitForRestart(
                  actorRef,
                  Some(PowerPlantCreateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg))
                )
              )

            case None =>
              log.warning(s"No running actor instance found for id $id :: Creating a new instance")
              self ! PowerPlantCreateEvent(id, powerPlantCfg)
          }

        case PowerPlantDeleteEvent(id, powerPlantCfg) =>
          log.info(s"Stopping PowerPlant actor with id = $id and type ${powerPlantCfg.powerPlantType}")

          context.child(s"$simulatorActorNamePrefix$id") match {
            case Some(actorRef) =>
              context.watch(actorRef)
              actorRef ! Kill

            case None =>
              log.warning(s"No running actor instance found for id $id")
          }
      }
```